# String To Dataframe PySpark/Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I was trying to convert the return of api from text (string) to a dataframe but I unfortunely I can't, is there any way to do this.

the text from API return with headers.

```
import requests

url = "test"

headers = {
    "accept": "text/csv",
    "authorization": "Bearer test"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=60)

print(response.text)
```

OUTPUT FROM API

`Device Type,OS Version,App Version,SDK Version,App ID,App Name,Bundle ID,Is Retargeting,Retargeting Conversion Type,Attribution Lookback,Reengagement Window,Is Primary Attribution,User Agent,HTTP Referrer,Original URL ,,2021-01-13 15:53:23,2023-01-01 01:32:37,uninstall,,,,,SDK,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,SA,BR,PE`

Comment: You may want to start with importing pandas

Comment: is the `url`  just `test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import requests

url = "test"

headers = {
    "accept": "text/csv",
    "authorization": "Bearer test"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=60)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), header=None)
print(df)
```